# which marshalling method is better?

Tags: c#, arrays, structure, marshalling

I found two method to convert `byte[]` to structure. but I don't know if there is any difference between these two methods? can anyone know which is better (performance, ...)?

**#1:**

```
public static T ByteArrayToStructure<T>(byte[] buffer)
{
    int length = buffer.Length;
    IntPtr i = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
    Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, i, length);
    T result = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(i, typeof(T));
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(i);
    return result;
}
```

**#2:**

```
public static T ByteArrayToStructure<T>(byte[] buffer)
{
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    T result = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
    handle.Free();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Better in what terms? By the way, I think the second one does not do what you expect. Did you test them? If so, show us the code you used to make sure the methods work as expected.

Comment: better in performance (i edited my post). are you sure #2 doesn't work?

Comment: OK. so there are some differences. can you tell more?

Comment: If you want to compare performance in your specific case, *you have to measure it by yourself*.

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad I were wrong sorry. They do the same. #1 does use unmanaged memory, #2 does only use managed memory. As stated out by `svick`, make a benchmark yourself.

Comment: As a question about `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()` vs `GCHandle.Alloc()` for this specific case it is rather interesting and doesn't deserve the standard "measure yourself" blurbs.

Comment: Now with benchmark provided by @GameScripting (+1) real question is: why do you want to go such route instead of regular serialization or reading with BinaryReader?

Comment: I am asking why **copy** memory at all. If you have a look how the `BitConverter` works, we don't need to copy any memory at all since the struct already is in memory?!

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov imagine you have several structure with lots of fields that layout on memory sequentially. I don't want to read all the fields of all the structures one by one. so I thought it is better to use a single method for reading and writing them to byte[]. so I read them as byte[] from the hard and parse them to structure. Of course I'm not sure the whole idea is correct or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a benchmark for you using the following code:

```
const int ILITERATIONS = 10000000;

const long testValue = 8616519696198198198;
byte[] testBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(testValue);

// warumup JIT
ByteArrayToStructure1<long>(testBytes);
ByteArrayToStructure2<long>(testBytes);

Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < ILITERATIONS; i++)
{
    ByteArrayToStructure1<long>(testBytes);
}

stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("1: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

stopwatch.Reset();

stopwatch.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < ILITERATIONS; i++)
{
    ByteArrayToStructure2<long>(testBytes);
}

stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("2: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

stopwatch.Reset();

stopwatch.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < ILITERATIONS; i++)
{
    BitConverter.ToInt64(testBytes, 0);
}

stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("3: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

Console.ReadLine();
```

I came to the following results:

```
1: 2927
2: 2803
3: 51
```

Comment: Side note: make sure to have warmup calls to exclude JIT and see if you actually call 2 different methods...